# How to divide two js files in different projects?

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript file that consists of a plugin made with "pattern evaluation module".

This file has to be in two different projects:

1) In the administration project is all the code of the plugin

2) In the public project it must be in the same js as in the admin project BUT it does not contain depending on what functions

 
The question is. How can I keep only one js and return some functions depending on where I call it (or whatever I call it)?

Code Example

```js
var MyPlugin = (function (param1) {
    let publicFunctions = {};
 
 let _param = param1;
 
 // I want this function to be loaded in both projects
 let function1 = function(){
  //...some code
 };
 
 // this function I want to load ONLY in one project, then I do not want the web publishes load this method so that it can not be used from the browser console
 let function2 = function(){
  //...some code
 };
 
 // I want this function to be loaded in both projects
 let function3 = function(){
  //...some code
 };
 
 
 publicFunctions.funciton1 = () => { return function1();}
 publicFunctions.funciton3 = () => { return function3();}
 
 return publicFunctions;
});
```

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - please incluse what you've tried, and what is going wrong with your method/attempt

Comment: I have added an example of my code and what I want to achieve.

My question is how can I do that when I call the js from my public project. Function 2 does not appear in the js.

I can create two different Js but I do not want to have to keep the two files parallel and I would like to refactor that public code to a single file

Comment: "*it does not contain depending on what functions*" - sorry, I'm having difficulties parsing that sentence

Comment: What is "pattern evaluation module"?

Comment: How is `function2` used in the admin project when it's not visible outside the module?

Comment: You could try '[Tree Shaking](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/tree-shaking)' as that (in theory) should extract the code that you use in your bundle.